# How can I add dots between page numbes in Laravel AJAX results

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm paginating my results which are displayed through AJAX request but I'm facing a problem with the pagination. Here's my pagination logic:

```js
if(reviews.pagination.next_page_url != null || reviews.pagination.current_page != 1) {

    var paginat = "";

    for (let p = 1; p <= reviews.pagination.last_page; p++) { 

        if (p === reviews.pagination.current_page) {
            paginat = paginat + '<span aria-current="page"><b class="active">' + p + '</b></span>';
        } else { 
            paginat = paginat + '<b>' + p + '</b>';
        }

    }
 
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceu8h.jpg) is an image what happens when the results are too many. How to minify this with `..` (dots) between the page numbers?

This is how I return pagination info:

```
return response()->json([
    'pagination' => collect($reviews->toArray())->except('data'),
   // ....
]);
```

Comment: This would need to happen inside the loop inside your first code block, that is where you are creating the page number links. You will need to do a bit of math and add some conditions there, depending on how exactly you want it to behave.

Comment: Well I'm able to do the math and build it as I expect to behave, but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Where is the _problem_? Your script currently outputs all page numbers, either wrapped in a span with `aria-current`, or plain as the content of a `b`. So what you need to do now, is amend the logic, so that it generates `...` for the first page number you do not want to show, and simply _nothing_ for all the following page numbers you don't want to show.

Comment: Yeah it sounds so simple but it isn't at all. What setup do I need for it? The current page and the maximum available pages? But then what.. I mean what should I actually calculate in order to define which pages to hide depending on the current page?

Comment: Well _which_ pages do you want to hide? _"depending on how exactly you want it to behave"_ was meant as a hint that you still need to define that, so far you haven't.

Comment: Probably like `1 ... 11 (12) 13 ... 24`. Where `12` is the current page.

Comment: The first and the last page number you want to show in any case, so write conditions that check for those. If the current `p` wasn't either of those - then check how far away it is from the current page. Use some flags maybe, to handle the _first_ of those pages that are too far away in either direction (because only for those you want to output `...`, and for the others nothing.) And then maybe add some fine-tuning for the edge cases (not enough pages before/after the current one for any `...` to be inserted before/after.)